# JavaScript AJAX Call OnComplete function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have to build an ajax site without the use of JQuery (which is a pain), So I have been trying to build ajax requests in a similar fashion.

Currently I have this:

```
function $ajax(json) {
    var xmlhtml;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhtml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhtml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhtml.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhtml.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhtml.status == 200) {
                alert(xmlhtml.responseText);
            }
            else if (xmlhtml.status == 400) {
                alert('There was an error 400');
            }
            else {
                alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhtml.open(json.type, json.url, true);
    xmlhtml.send();
};
```

and I call it like so:

```
(function () {
    $ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/stock"
    });
})();
```

which is fine, it returns my records. What I need to do is create callback functions for complete (status == 200) and error (status != 200).
How can I do this?

**Please note, I can not use jQuery.**

Comment: So...why can't you use jQuery? It's just a free library of functions that makes many tasks easier. You're going to need to do much more to build a sea-worthy ajax routine if you're gonna write it yourself.

Comment: It's great that you're not jumping off bridges by forcing 70KB down people's throats but please explain what `$ajax({`... is if it is not jQuery?

Comment: Why do you still support ancientIE?

Comment: because this application has to work on a scanner which has ie5.5 on it. Trust me when I say I can't use jQuery, I am not just saying it for the sake of it.

Comment: and John, $ajax is not jQuery, $.ajax is....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simplest way would be for your function to accept another parameter which is the function:

```
function $ajax(json, callback) {
    var xmlhtml;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhtml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhtml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhtml.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhtml.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhtml.status == 200) {
                callback(xmlhttp.responseText)
            }
            else if (xmlhtml.status == 400) {
                // don't ignore an error!
            }
            else {
                alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhtml.open(json.type, json.url, true);
    xmlhtml.send();
}
```

Which would let you do

```
$ajax({...}, function(response){
    // done here
})
```

As for your function itself, if you can use *modern* web browsers I'd do this slightly differently using promises. Like the above code this requires no external references but it does require a modern browser:

```
function xhr(params){
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
   xhr.open(params.type || "GET", params.url);

   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ 
       xhr.onload = function(e){
          if(xhr.status === 200) return resolve(xhr.responseText);
          return reject(new Error("XHR response not 200 " + xhr.status);
       };
       xhr.onerror = reject;
       xhr.send(params.data)
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks, this looks like it is just what I need. Going to test it out before I mark it and +1 it :d

Comment: @r3plica if this helped you - see if my more general answer here is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/16825593#16825593 Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: this is what I did : http://jsfiddle.net/1q39qme9/ I know it returns an error but you should get the idea from that

Comment: and yes, both posts helped. Thanks